# Need suggestion regarding customizing textarea max length function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2

i am using a function that limit textArea length. Although function is performing well but i want to ask whether i am calling function in right way?

Here it is

```
<h:inputTextarea id="questionInputTextArea"
                 value="#{faqAddUpdate.question}"
                 cols="50"
                 rows="3"
                 disabled="#{faqAddUpdate.buttonState}"
                 onkeypress="limitTextArea(this, 400)"
                 style="overflow: auto;">

   <f:validateLength maximum="200" />

</h:inputTextarea>
```

Here is the function

```
function limitTextArea(element, limit) {

    var $textArea = $(element);     //casting to jQuery so we can use jQuery functions on it
    ($textArea).keypress(function(event){

        if (event.which < 0x20) {

            // e.which < 0x20, then it's not a printable character
            // e.which === 0 - Not a character
            return;     // Do nothing

        }

        if ($textArea.val().length == limit) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if ($textArea.val().length > limit) {

            // Maximum exceeded
            $textArea.val() = $textArea.val().substr(0, limit);
        }

    }); //end of keypress

} //end of function()
```

The thing that confusing me is this, i am using **onkeypress** in my jsf code, and in the function i am also saying that **($textArea).keypress(function(event)**. How can i optimize this function? Or i am doing right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching a new keypress event listener everytime a key is pressed. This makes no sense. You need to *either* specify it straight in `onkeypress` attribute, *or* to attach it by jQuery means after document ready. Further the assignment to `val()` function makes no sense, you'd need to pass the new value as its argument instead. This can impossibly be "performing well". Finally, I'd also suggest to use `keyup` instead of `keypress` so that the function is only invoked *after* the value of the textarea is been updated which results in a more sane behaviour of the limit function. This way you also don't need to check for non-printable character ranges.

All with all, it can just look like this:

```
function limitTextArea(element, limit) {
    var $textArea = $(element);

    if ($textArea.val().length > limit) {
        $textArea.val($textArea.val().substr(0, limit));
    }
}
```

which is to be registered as

```
<h:inputTextarea ... onkeyup="limitTextArea(this, 400)" />
```

---

If you really need to attach it by jQuery `keyup()` function, then you'd have to specify the limit in the function yourself.

E.g.

```
<h:inputTextarea ... styleClass="limit" />
```

with

```
$("textarea.limit").keyup(function() {
    var $textarea = $(this);
    var limit = 400;

    if ($textarea.val().length > limit) {
        $textarea.val($textarea.val().substr(0, limit));
    }
});
```

*(which you execute during `$(document).ready(function() {...})` or `$(function() {...});`)*

---

Or you could specify the limit as part of class name and extract it accordingly:

```
<h:inputTextarea ... styleClass="limit_400" />
```

with something like this

```
$("textarea[class*=limit_]").each(function(i, textarea) {
    var classNames = textarea.className.split(' ');
    var limit = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
        if (classNames[i].indexOf("limit_") == 0) {
            limit = parseInt(classNames[i].split("_")[1]);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (limit) {
        $(textarea).keyup(function() {
            var $textarea = $(this);

            if ($textarea.val().length > limit) {
                $textarea.val($textarea.val().substr(0, limit));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

---

By the way, the limit of `400` doesn't match the limit which you've there in the server side `<f:validateLength>` validator.

Comment: HHmm can you tell me one thing please. If i want to use event object in my function how can i use it? Like i am just passing element and limit to my function. Can i also pass event object to my function like `onkeyup="limitTextArea(this, 400, event)" `. Thanks

Comment: Actually i used `event.which` becuase after reaching the maxlimit, if i press any key then you feel some shaky behaviour in textarea. Like textarea is trying to go to top, or try to prevent you from writing. It's scrollbar shake slightly. That's why i used `event.which` so user can't press a key once it reach the max limit

Comment: And the same reason for using keypress. If i use keyup event then you feel slightly shaky behavior when you press the key after reaching max limit. And yes it doesn't match :) I will correct it , as i was testing and was focusing on the function so i left it as it is. In-fact i used this approach by reading one of your answers on this forum ;). Thanks :)